# FB Messenger open URL in default browser

Tags: url, browser, hyperlink, default, messenger

working on bot conversation via FB Messenger - need to open a URL in default browser - so can flip back and forth between web exploration in browser with direction from bot via Messenger - so explicitly do not want link in Messenger to open in Messenger browser...

Comment: It seems to me, it's not obvious what the problem actually is. Please, consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 1):

to rephrase - I would like to know how to make a link that will not open in the messenger window when on mobile device - but will open in the default browser (likely Chrome for android, safari for ios) instead.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem